# Displaying PDF in Bootstrap modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, firefox

I'm really struggling with simple thing. What I want to achieve is simply displaying PDF using HTML `<object>` tag inside Bootstrap modal.

[I've created Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2IfTSBbUxmjk0BEMsT2H?p=preview) to demonstrate the problem. Basically under "Working PDF" is simple `<object>` tag, which works fine. Under "Working PDF - collapse" is PDF inside collapsed `div` and "Not working PDF - modal" demonstrates the issue.

I thought maybe the problem was with `display: none;`, but collapse example works, so it can't be related to visibility. On Chrome, which uses some native PDF viewer, everything works fine. 
My Firefox uses Adobe plugin, but when I switch back to pdf.js viewer - everything works as expected.

I also found [this example](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/VX7EN), which demonstrates, that displaying PDF in modal is working fine, when HTML is created inside Javascript function. I can't however understand how this is any different compared to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Check This. . https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/P3Vvm

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar well... I did check it, because I'm linking something very similar in my question. I'm uncertain how your link is supposed to help me.

Comment: ok sure........

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on how should I proceed with my solution based on your link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solved my own problem. It turned out, that CSS animations caused this unexpected behaviour.
In `modals.less` there is style declaration

```
.modal{
    &.fade .modal-dialog{
        .translate(0, -25%);
        .transition-transform(~"0.3s ease-out");
    }
    &.in .modal-dialog { .translate(0, 0) }
}
```

Those translates `.translate(0, -25%);` and `.translate(0, 0)` are causing problems, so I decided to declare my own mixin

```
.translate-none(){
    -webkit-transform: none;
        -ms-transform: none; // IE9 only
         -o-transform: none;
            transform: none;
}
```

and use it instead of those with animations

```
.modal{
    &.fade .modal-dialog {
    .translate-none();
    .transition-transform(~"0.3s ease-out");
    }
    &.in .modal-dialog { .translate-none() }
}
```

This **disables Bootstrap modal animation**, but allows PDF to render